# Active close vs passive close in terms of socket API?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

In TCP we say one side of the connection performs an "active close" and the other side performs a "passive close".

In terms of the Linux sockets API, how do you differentiate the active close and the passive close?

For example, suppose we have two connected Linux TCP sockets, A and P, that have exchanged information over the application-level protocol and they are both aware that it is time to close their sockets (neither expect to send or receive any more data to or from each other).

We want socket A to perform the active close, and for P to be the passive close.

There are a few things A and P could do.  For example:

- call shutdown(SHUT_WR)
- call recv and expect to get 0 back
- call close.
- something else

What combination of these things and in what order should A do?... and what combination of these things and in what order should P do?

Comment: *BOTH* A and P should be performing *ALL* of the steps you mentioned: `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`, then loop `recv()` until it returns <= 0, then `close()`. The first party to perform these steps starts the closure, and then the other party should perform the same steps once it detects the closure, so both parties are aware that both ends of the connection have been closed gracefully.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: So there is no way to control which side is the active close and which is the passive?

Comment: There is no real thing as "active" vs "passive" close. One party may passively detect a closure from the other party, but both parties still need to close their end of the connection. However, there is such a thing as "graceful" vs "abortive" close, depending on whether `shutdown()` is called and whether linger is enabled on the socket. You should always strive for graceful closes whenever possible.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "active close" and "passive close" are popular terms that have been in use for decades. Like many other C programmers of a certain age, I learned it from W. Richard Stevens _UNIX Network Programming_, but I'm sure they predate even his usage. That doesn't negate anything else you're saying, however. Certainly both sides of the connection should close as gracefully as circumstances permit.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Both sides have to close. The first one to do so is the 'active closer' (to use a terminology which I also dislike), and that may be defined by your application protocol, and for other reasons it is best if it is the client rather than the server, but from the point of view of simply terminating the connection it's irrelevant.

Comment: @ejp, as you say, both sides have to close (actively).  No passive closer exists in tcp.  When you send a `FIN` segment, you are telling the other side no more data is to be sent.  But you have to wait for the `FIN` from the peer to go (correctly) to the closed state.  But from the point of view of sockets, a passive close is when the other side signals its willingness to close the connection, and that happens asynchronously (so, in passive mode)

Answer (score 4):

> In terms of the Linux sockets API, how do you differentiate the active
>   close and the passive close?

The 'active' close is simply whichever side of the socket sends a `FIN` or `RST` packet first, typically by calling `close()`.

> What combination of these things and in what order should A do?... and
>   what combination of these things and in what order should P do?

In practice, most of this is application- and application-protocol specific. I will describe the minimum/typical requirement to answer your question, but your mileage may vary depending on what you are specifically trying to accomplish.

You *may* first call `shutdown()` on Socket A if you want to terminate communication in one direction or the other (or both) on Socket A. From your description, both programs already know they're done, perhaps due to application protocol messages, so this may not be necessary.

You ***must*** call `close()` on Socket A in order to close the socket and release the file descriptor.

On Socket P, you simply keep reading until `recv()` returns `0`, and then you ***must***  call `close()` to close the socket and release the file descriptor.

For further reading, there are a number of good tutorials out there, and [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#closedown) is quite popular.

Answer (score 1):

**Active open** is when you issue `connect(2)` explicitly to make a connection to a remote site.  The call blocks until you get the socket opened on the other side (except if you issued `O_NONBLOCK` `fcntl(2)` call before calling `connect(2)`.

**Passive open** is when you have a socket `listen(2)`ing on a connection and you have not yet issued an `accept(2)` system call.  The `accept(2)` call normally blocks until you  have a completely open connection and gives you a socket descriptor to communicate over it, **or gives you inmediately a socket descriptor if the connection handshake has already finished when you issue the `accept(2)` syscall**  (this is a passive open).  The limit in the number of passively open connections the kernel can accept on your behalf while you prepare yourself to make the `accept(2)` system call is what is called the `listen(2)` value.

**Active close** is what happens when you explicitly call `shutdown(2)` or `close(2)` system calls.  As with passive open, there's nothing you can do to make a **passive close** (it's something that happens behind the scenes, product of other side's actions).   You detect a **passive close** when the socket generates an *end of file* condition (this is, `read(2)` always returns `0` bytes on reading) meaning *the other end* has done a `shutdown(2)` (or `close(2)`) and the connection is *half (or full) closed*.  When you explicitly `shutdown(2)` or `close(2)` your side, it's an active close.

## NOTE

if the other end does an explicit `close(2)` and *you continue writing* on the socket, you'll get an error due to the impossibility of sending that data (in this case we can talk about a passive `close(2)` ---one that has occured without any explicit action from our side) but the other end can do a *half close* calling `shutdown(2)`.  This makes the tcp to send a `FIN` segment only and conserves the socket descriptor to allow the thread to receive any pending data in transit or not yet sent.  Only when it receives and acknowledges the other end's `FIN` segment will it signal you that no more data remains in transit.

Comment: "Passive open is when you have a socket listen(2)ing on a connection" is correct. The remainder of the paragraph is not. 'Passive open' refers to the listening socket itself. The rest of the first paragraph is about the `accept()` process, and whether or not there was alread a connection in the backlog queue when you call `accept()` is basically irrelevant to everything except whether `accept()` blocks.

Comment: @EJP, Yes, it is irrelevant, but *to know if a passive connect has occurred, you have to do the `accept(2)` syscall*, and/or check at least if it should block.  As you never get the connected socket, only by doing an `accept(2)` syscall, there's no other, unprivileged way to know from the socket interface that a passive connect has occurred. By definition, passive things happen to occur without active participation of the process/thread, so how can you know if passive connect has happened or not? The paragraph is the explanation to the issue, even if not related to the active/passive connect.

Comment: @EJP, yes, there's another way to know if a connect has occurred in the time between `listen(2)` and `accept(2)` system calls: doing a `select(2)` for reading in the listening socket, but the paragraph is not incorrect, as you say.